# hide and show two div on two condition using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to hide and show 2 different div on two condition

for example  when count value reach 0 i want to hide #id1 and show #id2 and when variable count value increase from  0  i want to reverse the effect how can i accomplish it with jquery thanks in advance..

```
var count=0
$(document).ready(function{      
   if(count == 0) {
      $('#id1').hide();
   }else{
      $('#id2').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Try `if( count === 0 )`

Comment: With only one equal sign, you're ~declaring~ assigning the variable instead of comparing it. ;)

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Hi eddie thanks for the example i tried with above condition its not reversing the effect when variable  count value increases

Comment: @Tico how to reverse the hide and show when variable value increase

Comment: @NithishPK the answer below should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count=0
$(document).ready(function{      
    if(count = 0)
    {
        $('#id1').hide();
        $('#id2').show();
    }else{
        $('#id2').hide();
        $('#id1').show();
    }
}
```